# Как отсортировать двумерный массив?

Tags: массивы, сортировка, java

Добрый день! Имеется задача, для решения которой, необходимо отсортировать двумерный массив в определенном порядке.

Допустим имеется массив строковых массивов:

```
{root, dir1, dir2, dir3, file1}:
{root, dir2, file}
{root, dir3, file}
{root, dir1, dir3,file}
{root, dir3, dir1, file}
{root, dir1, dir2}
{root, file}
```

Необходимо получить следующее:

```
{root, dir1, dir2, dir3, file1} 
{root, dir1, dir2} <--- 2
{root, dir1, dir3,file} <--- 3
{root, dir3, dir1, file} <--- 1
{root, dir3, file}
{root, dir2, file}
{root, file}
```

То есть, (попытаюсь объяснить простым языком, сильно не пинайте за объяснение) первой строкой мы выводим самый длинный массив, далее выводятся массивы, имеющие общие данные с первым массивом (до значения `root`). Когда эти массивы заканчиваются ищем обратно самый длинный из оставшихся(1) и в том же духе выводим как и в начале и так до конца.. Прошу так же обратить внимание на строку(2), ее длина меньше чем строки(3), но она на правильном месте, так как `dir2` является общей , а в строке(3) общей является `dir1`. В общем как-то так...Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

Comment: Ответ оказался на поверхности!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом то деле, если внимательно посмотреть на задачу - то задача не о сортировке двумерного массива, а задача о сортировке одномерного массива (если угодно массива строк) со специфическим компаратором.

Под компаратором в данном контексте понимается алгоритм сравнения строк - в том виде как это указано топикстартёром.

Осталось только реализовать это компаратор - в терминах Java реализовать интерфейс `java.util.Comparator` или `Comparable` и засунуть его в `sort()`

В общем сконцентрируйтесь на компараторе, остальное фигня.

Answer (score 0):

Так вы сами описали алгоритм. В чем проблема ?
Двумерный массив - массив ссылок на одномерные массивы. Что бы поменять строки достаточно свапнуть(поменять местами) ссылки на одномерные массивы. Найти строку(массив) которая больше всего похожа на данную не проблема. Дело техники.